# MOSS 2007; Added custom fields not showing up in NewForm, EditForm, DispForm

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have a menu action that is registered on every list.

This action when enabled, creates 4 custom fields. Field creation works on every list.

The problem is, that on the lists, which are created via our own Site Template, these 4 fields are not displayed on any forms (DispForm, NewForm, EditForm). On every other list, the fields are normally displayed.

This is my code for adding  field to the list (on field example):

```
 if (!list.Fields.ContainsField("RemindTo"))
        {
            list.Fields.Add("RemindTo", SPFieldType.Text, false);
            SPFieldText text = (SPFieldText)list.Fields["RemindTo"];
            text.Description = "Remind to email address, leave empty for Default value. (Default. author email address)";
            text.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            text.ShowInEditForm = true;
            text.ShowInNewForm = true;
            text.ShowInViewForms = true;
            text.Update();
        }
```

Any help is most welcome,

Regards,
Tom